# Find x in a multiple arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Consider the following sequences:

```
A : (4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, ...)   ..+3
B : (3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38, ...)  ..+7
C : (8, 19, 30, 41, 52, 63, ...)  ..+11
D : (1, 14, 27, 40, 53, 66, ...)  ..+13
```

How to calculate for example "41" in which sequence ?

PS: I'm looking for a fast method, because this numbers get higher to thousands of digits.

Comment: In sequence $C: 41=8+11+11+11.$

Comment: Write the general term of each sequence as $t_n=a+(n-1)d$ and substitute $t_n$ as $41$, the resulting $n$ should be an integer.

Comment: @Fred i need a sort of equation, this is juste an example the numbers get higher.

Comment: A priori, any given number might be in more than one of these progressions. $10$, for instance, is in both $A$ and $B$.  Or, like $5$, it might be in none of them.  Just check each one.  $A$, for example, consists of all the natural numbers $≥4$ which are $1$ more than a multiple of $3$.  $41$ isn't of that form, so it isn't in $A$.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu if a given number is in more than one of these progressions then, i only need the smallest which is A (+3), i can't try one by one, i need a fast method, because the given number will be large in another example.

Comment: Speed is really a minor objection here, since in each case you are just checking divisibility by a very small number.  Maybe if your test numbers are millions of digits long that's an issue but otherwise...

Comment: In any case, trying one by one is the only way to go.  If you only need the first success, then you can stop after you get it.

Comment: thanks @lulu in fact i will have thousands digit numbers. speed is really important, otherwise its a brute force.

Comment: This is the fastest way to check: Subtract the first number from $41$ and divide the number by difference term (I mean, the "+" term). Is the result an integer? If yes, stop. Otherwise, move on. Let's begin:
$$
\frac{41-4}{3} = 12.3333... 
$$
Not an integer. Next:
$$
\frac{41-3}{7} = 5.428...
$$
etc ...

Comment: Please edit your post to add more detail to your question.  I don't think anyone reading your post would imagine that the issue was a purely computational one related to the size of the test number.

Comment: In any case, you are essentially asking for a rapid way to test divisibility.  Depending on the divisor there may be rapid ways to test (for instance, it is much easier to test divisibility by $10$ than by $11$).  Still, even with thousands of digits I'd expect standard algorithms to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

These are four arithnmetic sequences whose nth term $T_n=A+D(n-1)$, where $A$ is the first term and $D$ is the common difference. Here 41 is the fourth term in the fourth sequence wit $A=8$ and $D=11$, so $41=8+3.11$